# Compare Set & List in my case

Tags: java, performance, swing, list, jakarta-ee

I have  a `List<Integer>` , this list contains duplicated elements:

```
//myList content is something like e.g. 1,2,1,3,3,6,7,...
List<Integer> myList = getNumbers();
```

I have also an `Set<String>` , as you all know, `Set` only contain unique elements, no duplicated one. My `Set<String>` contains String-type-integers:

```
//The Set content is String type integer , e.g. "1", "3", "5" …
Set<String> mySet = getNumSet();
```

I would like to compare `mySet` with `myList` to figure out what elements `mySet` has but `myList` doesn't have & remove those elements from `mySet`.

The way I do now is to use nested iteration like following:

```
for(Integer i : myList){
   for(String s : mySet){
         if(!myList.contains(Integer.valueOf(s))){
               mySet.remove(s);
         }
    }   

}
```

Is there more efficient way than mine to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for (Iterator<String> it = mySet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if(myList.contains(Integer.parseInt(it.next()))){
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: change your `if-statement` to `if(!myList.contains(Integer.parseInt(it.next())))`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way may be using [`Collection#retainAll(Collection<?> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) which could be implements with some optimization in function of the collection's type.

`mySet.retainAll(myList)`

However `mySet` and `myList` must be `Set<X>` and `List<X>`. I advice you to change the declaration of `mySet` and fill it with something like `Integer#valueOf(String s)`, then use the `retainAll` method.

Comment: It doesn't work! because `List<Integer>` and `Set<String>`. He need to use `Iterator`

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the set.
2. Iterate through the list, removing found items from 
   the copy.
3. Subtract the copy from the original set.

Suppose you have *m* elements in the set and *n* elements in the list.

Then removing items from the set is *O(log m)* and iterating through the list is *O(n)*. The overall complexity is *O(n × log m)*. The subtraction is at most *O(m × log m)*, so the overall complexity is *O(s × log s)* where *s = max(m, n)*.

The complexity of your algorithm is *O(n<sup>2</sup> × (log m)<sup>2</sup>)*, because you

1. iterate over the list (*O(n)*) and for each item
2. iterate through the set (*O(log m)*),
3. finding the corresponding item in the list (*O(n)*), and finally
4. removing it from the set if appropriate (*O(log m)*).

Comment: Why is this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Actually more information is needed to find out the best approach.

If myList.size() >> mySet.size(), follow Oswald's solution, or

1. Create a new Set of String.
2. For each item in myList, if it's not in mySet, save it to the newSet.
3. call mySet.removeAll(newSet).

If mySet.size() >> myList.size(), the best solution would be convert myList to a new Set of String,  and then call mySet.retainAll method.